# Is alpha channel used when loading JPEG image as ARGB_8888?

Tags: android, image, jpeg

JPEG format of images doesn't support transparency. [Reference.](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/jpeg-faq/part1/section-12.html)

`ARGB_8888` is the default format for loading images on Android. [Reference.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPreferredConfig)

So, if I load JPEG image as `ARGB_8888`, 8 bits of alpha channel are just not used on every pixel?

To not lose memory, it should be loaded as `RGB_888`, right? But such [`Bitmap.Config`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html) doesn't exist. Why?

It will be perfect for huge JPEG images. I don't mind a little slower processing. Memory is crucial to me. Is it better to just lose 25% of memory, just because there is no `RGB_888` option?

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer to this question very dependent to the circumstances you're in. Is there a memory issue, or space, or bandwidth that would deter you from using `ARGB_8888`? If not, than use it.

According to the documentation,

> It should be used whenever possible.

**EDIT**

Since RGB_888 is not a default `Bitmap.Config` option, but `RGB_565` is, which uses 2 bytes compared to 4 as `ARGB_8888`, you'll end up going back to making your decision based on the circumstances.

Are you willing to drop image quality and used memory for the required processing power?

Comment: I rephrased my question. I'm just asking, isn't it just silly losing of memory? I'm not asking about any use case, if I should use `ARGB_8888` or not :)

Comment: `ARGB_8888` is the default option. [Reference.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPreferredConfig) I'm willing to drop processing power for memory. I'm not willing to drop image quality.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk Then you might end up making your own conversion since `RGB_565` uses only 2KB.

Comment: 2KB? But for what this 2KB? We don't know the size of the image. I don't understand this 2KB...

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk My mistake. I meant 2B not 2KB.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, internally the renderer could be designed to work with 4 channels images when performing image operations. Uploading a 3 channel image may save memory, but also require a special operations case. In the case of GPU accelerated graphics this could be an even bigger problem (an GPU driver would probably generate a fake alpha channel).